Cannot GET / with Aginx proxy
I try to make two projects running on a Azure VM. (let say app1 and app2.) Express apps.
proxy by Aginx as below:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name domain.online;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }

    location /pos/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

    }
}

app1 works on /
app2 does NOT work on /pos, browser shows Cannot GET /
I use console.log find that
app.js is works,
routes is wroks,
routes/index.js works,
routes/modules/home.js works, because log shows 'home'
routes/modules/home.js as below and
console did not show 'get /'
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

console.log('home')
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('get /')
  res.render('index')
})

module.exports = router

apps work on localhost.
apps work on vm with docker image.
I don't know why I cannot get the url or anything I missed?
I tried revised my app, routes for /pos or domain.online/pos but not works.
I thinkg console shows home means the url and ports setting is find.
But I just cannot GET / by router.get

You tagged this as [tag:docker]; which parts (if any) are running in containers, and how do you start them?  When you say "it works on localhost", is "localhost" the end user's system running the browser, your server instance, or any of the container-private localhosts?

about docker: I make a gitlab-ci.yml to build docker image and then push to gitlab container registry.  Then run -d- p 8080:8080 that image on vm
about localhost, I check image is fine by followings:

I try on localhost:3000 on my PC.
I connect to vm and chekc the image by $ docker images and $ docker run that image on port 8080:8080. And I also use $docker logs contianerID to check log where I find the console.log is break before router.get('/', (req, res)...)


hey! I solve this by revise ansible setting as proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; without the / in the END.
